# WPF: MaskedTextBox + SetCaret

Tags: wpf, wpftoolkit, maskedtextbox

So I am currently using the WPF Extended Toolkit with the MaskedTextBox and have the mask set up as:

**(000) 000-000**
which is the format for a phone number.

I have a problem that if the user selects the textbox with a mouse click the caret goes to the position where the cursor was (unless the cursor is beyond the scope of the mask then the caret defaults to the end.

If I tab into the textbox it sets the caret to right after the opening parenthesis which is what I'm looking for but it does not behave the same way with a mouse click.

I have tried the following:

**Tried overriding in the actual toolkit file like this with mousedown, mouseup, ongotfocus and such.**

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    this.Select(1,0);
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
}
```

**Tried to also set events on the actual MaskedTextBox itself with the code behind.**

I've searched all over the internet and still nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you; in the markup:

```
<xctk:MaskedTextBox x:Name="MyMaskedTextBox"  Mask="(000) 000-000" PreviewMouseDown="MyMaskedTextBox_PreviewMouseDown"></xctk:MaskedTextBox>
```

And the event handler:

```
private void MyMaskedTextBox_PreviewMouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    MyMaskedTextBox.Focus();
    MyMaskedTextBox.Select(1, 0);
    e.Handled = true;            
}
```

Comment: Precisely what I'm looking for. If you just do OnMouseDown it doesn't change properly due to the direct event I suppose. The "tunneling" event associated with Preview is what I needed.